# Python Cerberus: problem with validation different schemas using 'anyof_schema' rule

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I am trying to use Cerberus to validate a list that contains strings or dictionaries using `anyof_schema` rule as proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506324/4643677):

```py
from cerberus import Validator

A = {'type': 'dict',
     'schema': {'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': True},
                'run': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}}}
B = {'type': 'string', 'empty': False}

schema = {
    'some_field': {
        'type': 'list',
        'anyof_schema': [A, B]
    }
}

v = Validator(schema)

challenge = {
    'some_field': ['simple string 1', {'name': 'some name', 'run': 'some command'}]
}

print(v.validate(challenge))
print(v.errors)
```

But validation fails, output:

```
False
{'some_field': ['no definitions validate', {'anyof definition 0': [{0: ['must be of dict type']}], 'anyof definition 1': [{1: ['must be of string type']}]}]}
```

It seems that `anyof_schema` rule works only if all schemas in the provided set describe the same data type (e.g. dictionaries).

Why `anyof_schema` rule fails in my case and how can I resolve this problem?

I am using Python 3.5.3 and Cerberus 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your schema looks expanded like this:

```
{"some_field": {
    "anyof" : [
        {"schema": …},
        {"schema": …},
    ]
}}
```

which means that whole list is validated against only one of the variants per rules set contained by *anyof*.

Thus you just need to swap *anyof* and *schema* in your hierarchy:

```
{"some_field": {
    "schema" : {
        "anyof":[
            {"type": "dict", …},
            {"type": "str", …},
        ]
    }
}}
```

This validates each item of the list against the allowed variants and these can therefore be of various 'shape'.